# Use count value for case in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to count total rows of particular condition and use that value in case condition.
What am i doing wrong here?
Please help...

```sql
        select count(*) as total 
        CASE 
            when total > 3
            Then 
                'true'
            else

                'false'
        end as result
        from friendship where userId = '1'
```

Comment: Please add data example and expected results in text format. The query in the question  is invalid

Comment: Output column alias cannot be used in another column expression. Use original expression instead. `... CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 3 THEN ...`

Comment: @ErgestBasha i guess it's mentioned clearly

Comment: @Akina still getting error

Comment: @KusalBackup *I guess it's mentioned clearly*, if it was I will not ask for clarification. Next time consider reading [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: @KusalBackup if so then you did something wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer to column aliases within the same `select` statement, the expressions are not evaluated in a "left to right" order.

Simply repeat the expression:

```
select Count(*) as total, 
  case when Count(*) > 3 then 'true' else 'false' end as result
from friendship 
where userId = 1;
```